# Set microphone level to a certain value on Windows 8

Tags: python, windows, audio

My microphone gets randomly set to full blast, and I'm looking for a way to keep it at a set level. It doesn't really matter how it changed. I don't care if I have to use regedit or if I have to run a script every time to change it, I just need a reliable way to keep my mic volume to a certain level.

edit: Should have been more clear, I obviously know how to change it manually. I'm looking for a more feasible option, as it needs to be changed around a dozen times per day. Autohotkey has audio controls, but I couldn't get it working. There might be a way to control audio levels with Python and winapi, but I don't where to being in regards to that.

Answer (score 1):

I made a script in AutoHotKey that works. However, you'll have to modify it with the appropriate DeviceNumber, which will vary system to system.

In short, the script sets the Mic volume level to a level specified, waits a half second, then loops indefinitely. Pressing the PAUSE key kills the script. A more thorough explanation is contained within the script itself.

JeffC, please note that I have the volume set at 100 here, but since your microphone is too high, you'd obviously want to change that number to a lower, acceptable volume.

The root cause of the problem for me was Google Hangouts. It auto adjusts mic volume during calls and doesn't set it back. Skype also does this by default, but has an option to not auto adjust the mic levels. There is no such option in Hangouts. For me, the volume would be set too low. Either way, running this script should work constantly refresh the microphone to your desired volume level. I'm only running it while on Hangout calls, if you wanted to run it all the time, you'd probably want to increase the sleep interval.

Greater explanation for everything is contained within the script, as is the link to the soundcard analysis script referenced there ( https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm#Ex ).

... Yeah, I'm not a programmer and am not sure how to post code here & don't see attachment options, so I'll just link you to my Google Hangouts Support forum post where I put the AHK script.

If you do know how to post code on here, feel free to paste it for anyone else who is having this problem

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/hangouts/qwq2LtDGLys/DQby-9lwCwAJ

Answer (score 0):

**

### OPTION ONE

**

**1** Type in "microphone" in the Start menu in Windows 8 and click where it says "Settings."

**2** Select the "Manage Audio Devices" option that has a speaker icon in the top left corner of the screen.

**3** Click on the "Recording" tab in the Sound window that appears.

**4** Select the microphone that you want to change to in the Recording tab. You'll see a green check mark next to your current microphone, as well as a series of bars next to it to show whether it's active.

**5** Click "Set default" to change the microphone. You can also click "configure" if it still needs configuration. Click "Apply," and then "OK" to keep the settings.

**

### OPTION TWO

**

From the Windows 8 Desktop Screen, right-click on the ‘Sound’ icon and from the options displayed, select ‘Recording Devices’.

Right-click on the active microphone. Active microphone has a green check-mark marked against it. Depending upon the setup there may be multiple microphones present.

Again, right-click the active mic and select the ‘Properties’ option.

Then, under the Microphone Properties window, from the ‘General’ tab, switch to ‘Levels’ tab and adjust the boost level.

By default, the level is set at 0.0 dB. You can adjust it up to +40 dB using the slider provided.

Be sure to carry out the process during your conversation so that you get the feedback from the other end immediately. This will also tell you whether the adjustments made are appropriate or not.

THATS IT..

Comment: I'm using an Audio Technica USB mic and it doesn't have boost. Also, the level randomly changes throughout the day, so the whole point is to make the process faster than manually changing it. I know AutoHotkey has functionality for this, but I couldn't get it working. I have basic knowledge of Python, but I wouldn't know where to start with regards to controlling audio.